# How can i handle the key that was left to the Right control key

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to handle the key that was left to the Right cntrl key which is equivalent to Mouse right click.

Comment: You mean the one that pops up a little context menu when you press it, like you say a mouse right click, right?

Comment: Ya exactly. I would like to show the context menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Apps)
    {
        // the key in question was pressed (key code = 93)
    }
}
```

Comment: It is giving nothing as you said i write like this in bettwen that code  contextmenu.show() but it is not getting displayed

Comment: Your localisation/keyboard settings may be precluding it. Alternatively you may have a weird keyboard. Also, I've never heard it referred to as an 'Apps' key before?

Comment: I didn't get yoy what you said

Answer (score 0):

This page about [Key Events in SeaMonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/editor/key-event-spec.html) has this info:

> Platform special keys (Windows key, contextual menu key on Windows, Macintosh startup key, monitor control keys, etc.) do not propagate events. They should be handled in platform code if necessary.

So you may not be able to bind to that particular key. However, there may be something available at [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) to help you out.