# Recognizing the Menu Key in KeyDown

Tags: c#, forms, keydown

I want to do something when the user pushes [this button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key), when inside a textbox. This is what I tried:

```
private void txtInvisible_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Menu)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("the context menu key was pressed");
    }
}
```

I tried Keys.L for example, and that triggered it. So maybe the Keys.Menu is the wrong key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `Keys.Apps`.

See these other questions:
[How can i handle the key that was left to the Right control key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616774/how-can-i-handle-the-key-that-was-left-to-the-right-control-key)
[What does WPF call the "Menu" key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329555/what-does-wpf-call-the-menu-key)

Answer (score 2):

Like stated before. keys.Apps is what you are looking for. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) you can find all the keys

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `Keys.Apps` key.

```
private void txtInvisible_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Apps)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("the context menu key was pressed");
    }  
}
```

Comment: Edited. I was using WPF.